# Azure AD Graph API - App Role Assignments List

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

There is no documentation around how the Application Role Assignments list that is generated from this AAD Graph API call is determined:

https://graph.windows.net/contoso.com/users/simon@contoso.com/appRoleAssignments

For instance, if the user has Office 365, no assigned Office 365 Apps appear in the Graph API response, yet if this user browses to https://myapps.microsoft.com/contoso.com they see them listed.

Can someone clarify the logic used to build the Apps returned in this list and if it is possible to retrieve *all* the applications assigned to the user?

Comment: This call seems to provide the O365 items you have access to: https://graph.windows.net/contoso.com/users/simon@contoso.com/assignedPlans, but the challenge is that you can't convert them into Application objects, though this may not be an issue if you consider SharePoint's tenant name can be guessed, along with Yammer.

Answer (score 1):

The user's `appRoleAssignments` navigation property should contain all of the roles that the user has been assigned on apps. In case an app does not declare any appRoles that can be assigned to users, there will still be one entity here with an all-zeros GUID.

For example, I've assigned one of my test users to an app that has no roles, and `Get-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId user-object-id` returns:

```
DeletionTimestamp    :
ObjectId             : 1YoOkUy2bESZDaQwZRhU0S-UYlhvd3FJsJikOAWHrsI
ObjectType           : AppRoleAssignment
CreationTimestamp    : 17.1.2016 15.40.03
Id                   : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
PrincipalDisplayName : Test User
PrincipalId          : 910e8ad5-b64c-446c-990d-a430651854d1
PrincipalType        : User
ResourceDisplayName  : TodoService
ResourceId           : 6b5b5ad6-54ce-415f-ad04-0a276ce086b0
```

And also one for an app that does specify roles:

```
DeletionTimestamp    :
ObjectId             : 1YoOkUy2bESZDaQwZRhU0YAvk4B2fQdPqcTGnjNiP_0
ObjectType           : AppRoleAssignment
CreationTimestamp    :
Id                   : 06608f41-55fb-400a-8da2-3d51909a0449
PrincipalDisplayName : Test User
PrincipalId          : 910e8ad5-b64c-446c-990d-a430651854d1
PrincipalType        : User
ResourceDisplayName  : TestApp
ResourceId           : ecf84db8-3333-43d0-809a-aaef620a14bf
```

Note the **Id** property specifies the id of the role that the user has on that app. In the case of the first one, they just have general access.

As for why Office 365 apps don't show up there, if I recall correctly you do not assign them the same way through the Azure AD user management? The app assignments may be an internal thing in O365 and Azure AD does not know about it. License assignments can be found from the `licenseDetails` navigation property of the user (or `Get-AzureADUserLicenseDetail` with Azure AD v2 PowerShell).